# Is there a way to authorize an express session in a post request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post, express-session

I'm trying to confirm a user is making a post request so that way any one can't just post to the URL and do something malicious. How can I do this using express-session? Or is there a better way to do it?

I've tried this but I guess session doesn't exist in req post.

```
router.post('/delete', function (req, res, next) {
  if (req.session.user.role === 'owner') {
    // Authorized
    // delete user here then redirect
    res.redirect('/admin');
  } else {
    // Unauthorized
    return res.redirect('/');
  }
})
```

Comment: Are you using the session middleware? That aside: there are *many* ways auth/auth can be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in many ways. One way is to send tokens in headers. To perform authorization, can use middlewares. as follows

Authentication Middleware :-

```
const auth = (req, res, next) => {
    const token = req.header('auth-token');
    if(!token) return res.status(401).send('Access denied. No token provided.');

    try{
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, 'PRIVATE KEY'); // decoding token
        req.user = decoded; // add token details to req
        next();
    }catch (ex){
        res.status(400).send('Invalid Token');
    }
}
```

Authorization Middleware :-

```
const admin = (req, res, next) => {
    if(!req.user.isAdmin) return res.status(403).send('Access denied.');

    next();
}
```

in router you can simply use middleware which will take care of authentication and authorization

```
router.post('/delete', [auth, admin],  function (req, res, next) {
  // do required operation
})
```

Comment: this looks good, only problem is I can't seem to figure out how to set the 'auth-token' header.

Comment: You have to set it to a incoming request. What's the UI framework that you are using?

Comment: Right now i'm not using any framework, just trying to set up the backend. This is my first big project.

Comment: How you are testing your API's?

Comment: i'm using express for the backend and then rendering pages with ejs to test.

Comment: While sending requests you can set headers containing auth-token

Comment: I don't understand, sorry. Could you please demonstrate in some code? I've tried req.header("auth-token", token); but when I get the headers I don't see auth-token.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't worked with ejs. You can use postman to test APIs, there you have an option to add headers as key value pair.